# Swagger can support multi method[GET,POST,...]

Tags: php, symfony, swagger

Do swagger support it?

`swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: API Documentation
  description: API Documentation
  version: 1.0.0
host: localhost
basePath: /test/v1
schemes:
  - http
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /test/v1/method1:
     get:
        ......
     get2:
        ......`

I have one the api, and I have much request with parameter are difference for all these.
How do?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can't have 2 different GET methods on the same endpoint, so I'd guess, no. What is the usecase for this?

Comment: my case: with each parameter will return results have format json difference

Comment: Without knowing specifically what "format difference" are, are you sure it shouldn't be a different end-point?

Comment: no, It be a different endpoint